# Moving Jobs between views in Hudson

Tags: jenkins, hudson, hudson-plugins

I have a lot of jobs in hudson and multiple views as well. What I want is to move jobs between views. E.g. Job1 is part of view1, I want to move that job from view1 to view2, how it is possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must be **administrator** (in version 1.X at least) to do that.

Go to the target view > click on the left (as an administrator) onto "Edit View" > **select** all desired job (with a regexp if you want or through checkboxes)

Go to the old view > click on the left (as an administrator) onto "Edit View" > **deselect** all desired job (with a regexp if you want or through checkboxes).

Quite easy, isn't it ? Or did I missed something ? If so, please be more explicit.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Self explanatory = Edit in Jenkins job]

!!! You need root privileges. Ask for these to your Admin.